# How to set nsec to zero for a time.Time typed value

Tags: go

There's a time.Time value created from current time, is there any quick way to set its "nsec" field to zero? As this part in my case is not useful to map to a second level date time field in mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`time.Truncate`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) with `time.Second`:

> Truncate returns the result of rounding t down to a multiple of d (since the zero time). If d <= 0, Truncate returns t unchanged.

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/go-IdYU18E.